# Low-cost Up-Down Servo solution

Tags: arduino, pic, pcb, design, servo

I have a small project and I'm interested "upgrading" to a more produce-efficient design. Please note I'm no electrical engineer.
I want to move a small servo (like this one http://www.hobbypartz.com/topromisesg9.html) 170 degrees on one tactile button hit, and all the way back when hit again. The whole thing should be powered from a 5V car USB charger.

I've implemented my prototype using an ATTiny85 (way overkill..) programmed using Arduino IDE, manual PWM (delaymicroseconds()) and one byte of EEPROM.

I'm looking for the most low-cost (and on secondary importance - lightweight and small) solution for this application. I don't expect any design schematics just ideas on implementation. There are no further "restrictions".

Also if there is a better way than servos for the same usage (still focus on low-cost and wieght), I'll be pleased to hear about.

Thanks for answerers.

Comment: I don't see why ATTiny is an overkill.

Comment: I would be careful with attempting to generate your own PWM signals to drive those servos. Driving a servo requires a 50Hz signal with a duty cycle that varies from about 5% to 15% depending on the angle of deflection desired. If you are manually generating those pulses it may be out of spec for the servo controller's input. That being said, if you are going to use Arduino libraries then just include and use the [servo](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/servo) one.

Comment: The lowest cost is zero and the lightest weight is probably some subatomic particle. Since neither of those is feasible, why don't you tell us what your actual cost and weight targets are and we can see what's possible.

Comment: @Dzarda ATTiny85 has way more in every spec than what I need. One example is the attiny13 which is much cheaper and should work in the same way. Just never tried it.

Comment: @sherrellbc I remember having issues using the servo library on the attiny. I've calculated the range for the delays manually and played with it a few times. It works, so I don't think it'll change behaviour over time.

Comment: @lyndon: Let's suppose that weight is not an issue. I doubt you can achieve zero cost. Firstly the cost of my prototype is too high. I can't give you an exact target cost because I don't know what are the options, and I'm certain that for any implementation you can pay less and more in different places and with different quantities. So in that matter, let's say I want to make 1000 pieces.

Comment: That's interesting because those libraries are incredibly trivial to use. I have read of certain bugs for particular hardware, but the servos you linked to are about as basic as they come. You use a few of their member functions like `attach()` and create a servo object. After which you simply `obj.write()` to a particular angle.

Comment: How many bytes of program memory does the current implementation require? Also, how many GPIOs and timers are consumed?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh As for GPIOs, I've used 1 pin for input from button, 1 pin for output to servo, vcc and gnd.
I do not know how to answer your two other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest, cheapest, most reliable solution will use a small, 6-pin microcontroller: VCC, GND, input, output, with two pins left to spare.

If you're not after necessarily smallest nor the cheapest, but are after low-tech, then a double 555 (say LMC556/TLC556) would do: one half would act as a toggle F-F, another one as a PWM generator, using the input from the first half to change the pulse width. This has a bunch of passive components, so it will cost more than a little 6 pin micro that only needs a capacitor to run.

An implementation using a cheap double (or quadruple) op-amp would work as well - again, at the reliability cost of passive parts.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. Can you direct me to a recommended 6 pin microcontroller?

Comment: PIC10f200 would be an obvious candidate.